# For Loop to look up items in the dock

Tags: bash, for-loop

Hi I'm trying to figure out a way to run a loop that detects what is currently on the dock and moving/deleting it.

I'm using docktuil.

I figured out the following line works great if the app I'm looking for is only one word ie.. Terminal, Notes. when I run the line it would out put "found"

```
~ % /usr/local/bin/dockutil --find "Notes" | awk {'print $3'}
    found
```

Just for context if I remove `| awk {'print $3'}`
I get this

```
Notes was found in persistent-apps at slot 3 in /Users/UserName/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
```

But if I have apps that I'm looking for that are two ie Microsoft Word, Microsoft Outlook. The line above doesn't work that well.

Is there a way i can do lookup without worrying how many words are for an app.

`

```
#specifies the label of the apps to be removed from the Dock.
apps="Terminal 'Microsoft Office'"

for apps in $apps
do
dockicon=$(/usr/local/bin/dockutil --find "$apps" | awk {'print $3'})
if [[ $dockicon == found ]]
then
/usr/local/bin/dockutil --remove "$apps" --allhomes --no-restart
echo "$apps is gone from the dock."
else
echo "$apps not found."
fi
done`
```

Comment: consider updating the question to show the complete output from `dockutil --find "$apps"` that shows both single-word and multi-word app names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can achieve it with this:

```
/usr/local/bin/dockutil --find "Notes" | grep "not found" &> /dev/null && echo "not found" || echo "found"
```

so you grep for "not found" and echo "not found" in this case, if grep didn't find "not found", then echo "found". `grep` is considered failed, if it didn't find anything, so `||` comes in handy. `&> /dev/null` discards output of a program (stdout and stderr), so you won't get actual grep results.
Or you can use exit code, if dockutil  does this correctly.if it does, this is the better way.

```
/usr/local/bin/dockutil --find "Notes" &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "found"; else echo "not found"; fi
```

`$?` is exit-code. It should be 0 if item was found and non-zero otherwise. I never used dockutils, so not sure.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just a quick question what does > /dev/null do.

Comment: @AlbertChan it redirects output of command to nowhere. if you remove this part, you'll get the string, returned by dockutils before "not found" text. give it a try - you'll see yourself :-)

Comment: @AlbertChan but, i'd recommend trying the second method, if aplicable. Who knows, maybe one day there will be item in the dock with "not found" in it's name.

Comment: Lol could be. Thanks for that. The only problem left is when i put the new into my script, it still separate the words. '  apps=( 'Microsoft Outlook' )

for apps in $apps
do
dockicon=$(/usr/local/bin/dockutil --find "$apps" | grep "not found" > /dev/null && echo "not found" || echo "found")
if [[ $dockicon == found ]]
then
/usr/local/bin/dockutil --remove "$apps" --allhomes --no-restart
echo "$apps is gone from the dock."
else
echo "$apps not found."
fi
done '

Comment: @AlbertChan just change the IFS to what it actually is in your list and don't forget to unset it after your loop.